# Memory leak with TPUs on GKE causing OOM/"Unavailable: Socket Closed" error

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, memory-leaks, tpu

I am using preemptible v2.8 Google Cloud TPUs to perform large-scale hyperparameter optimization. I created the nodes using GKE with tensorflow 2.3 (the latest available version for Cloud TPUs.) Unfortunately, I keep encountering a memory leak on the TPU nodes during the search. This memory leak seems to ultimately cause an "Unavailable: Socket Closed" error (or sometimes an OOM error), where the TPU becomes unable to perform any additional training or evaluation even after re-deploying the code. The problem does not occur when I test my code on either a CPU or GPU.

This problem only occurs on the TPU worker node, but not the controller CPU. (At one point, I had been encountering another memory leak on the CPU due to a buildup of old models and unnecessary operations on the computation graph.) Methods such as  `tf.backend.clear_session()` and `del model` resolved the memory leak with the CPU, but it persists on the TPU. Here is a graph of the TPU runtime memory usage (the decrease in memory at the end appears to occur after the TPU disconnects because GKE deletes it automatically):

[image: TPU runtime memory usage graph]

Ultimately, as the used memory increases on the TPU, I get the following error:

```
raise_from tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: 9 root error(s) found.

Error
2021-08-02T16:36:47.652282141ZHint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
Error
2021-08-02T16:36:47.652288611Z
Error
2021-08-02T16:36:47.652296423Z (4) Resource exhausted: {{function_node __inference_train_function_37854}} Attempting to reserve 3.27G at the bottom of memory. That was not possible. There are 3.48G free, 0B reserved, and 1.67G reservable.
Error
2021-08-02T16:36:47.652313550Z [[{{node cluster_train_function/_execute_4_0}}]]
2021-08-02T16:36:47.652921274Z0 successful operations.
Error
2021-08-02T16:36:47.654639274Z0 derived errors ignored.
```

Occasionally, I instead get an "Unavailable: Socket Closed" error or an "Unable to destroy remote tensor handles" error.

This error typically only occurs after training several networks. I tried multiple methods suggested by other posts to fix the error, such as typecasting my data to float32, not caching my dataset into memory, using a smaller mini batch size to decrease memory consumption, and using "from_logits=True" in my cost function. I even tried using multiprocessing to perform the network training so memory would be cleared after each network evaluation, but for some reason, the Cloud TPU fails to execute any of the for loops in my code or in the training code (a problem I did not have with either a GPU or CPU, cloud or otherwise.) Larger networks seem to cause the problem to occur much more quickly than smaller networks, which suggests to me that old, unused models are still kept in memory on the TPU. Is there any way to clear the memory on the TPU or reset its state to stop this memory leak?

Here is an MVE I wrote to duplicate the problem:

```
import os
import gc
import sys
import random
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn import metrics
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer, Conv2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

h = 128
w = 128
channels = 1

mini_batch_size = 256
epochs = 15


using_tpu = True
if using_tpu:
    ## Get tpu name from arguments
    tpu_name = sys.argv[1]
    tpu_name = tpu_name.replace('--tpu=', '')

    ## Initialize TPU
    tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu_name)  # TPU detection
    print('Running on TPU ', tpu.cluster_spec().as_dict()['worker'])

    tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
    tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
    tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)


def create_network():
    strategy = tf.distribute.TPUStrategy(tpu)
    with strategy.scope():

        ## Create random data
        x_train = np.random.randn(1024, 128, 128, 1).astype('float32')  # astype necessary to help prevent Connect to Socket Error
        y_train = np.random.randn(1024, 50).astype('float32')

        x_test = np.random.randn(256, 128, 128, 1).astype('float32')
        y_test = np.random.randn(256, 50).astype('float32')

        model = Sequential()
        model.add(InputLayer((h, w, channels)))


        layers = 5
        ks = [np.random.choice([3, 5, 7]) for l in range(layers)]
        filters = [np.random.choice([64, 128, 256]) for l in range(layers)]

        for l in range(layers):
            model.add(
                    Conv2D(kernel_size=(ks[l], ks[l]), padding='same',
                           filters=filters[l], name='conv' + str(l), activation='relu'))

        model.add(Flatten())
        # Softmax output layer
        model.add(Dense(50))  # Don't need softmax activation because from_logits performs that operation automatically

        lr = 0.001
        opt = Adam(learning_rate=lr, decay=1e-6)

        model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=mini_batch_size, shuffle=True, verbose=1)

    ##### memory leak also occurs with dataset API:
    '''
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(mini_batch_size,
                                                                                 drop_remainder=True)  

    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=epochs, verbose=1, shuffle=shuffle,
              steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // mini_batch_size)
    '''
    #######

    y_pred = model(x_test)

    ## Attempt to clear memory
    print(gc.collect())
    del model
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()


while True:
    create_network()
```

Thank you so much! Please let me know if I should include any other information.

Comment: Facing the same issue. These socket closed errors were less frequent on TPUv3, so I think memory exhaustion is the only issue.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Your error message:

```
(4) Resource exhausted: {{function_node __inference_train_function_37854}} Attempting to reserve 3.27G at the bottom of memory. That was not possible. There are 3.48G free, 0B reserved, and 1.67G reservable.
```

indicates an HBM OOM rather than a memory OOM. Basically the TPU has its own set of memory on the chips - in this case you've exhausted that memory. If it was an OOM (like RAM OOM), then you will likely see the `SocketClosed` error, which you saw as well.

- That being said, what are your options? I suggest you go with the `tf.data` approach but with a few modifications:

```
def get_dataset(is_training: bool):
  def generate_data(_):
    return tf.random.normal([128, 128, 1], dtype=tf.bfloat16)

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(1)
  dataset = dataset.repeat()
  dataset = dataset.map(generate_data, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
  dataset = dataset.repeat().batch(mini_batch_size, drop_remainder=is_training)

train_dataset = get_dataset(is_training=True)
eval_dataset = get_dataset(is_training=False)
```

In this example we can use bfloat16 which reduces the memory footprint on HBM, but you may need to further reduce your minibatch size from 1024 to 512. Alternatively you can go up from v2-8 to v3-8 which has 2x the HBM. I'm not sure if the `numpy` based method contributes to the OOMs/`SocketClosed` errors you see, but I don't think this approach should run into that. Of course you'll eventually use real data, and in that case you should use `tf.data` for optimal performance. More info [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/datasets).

- IIUC `tf.backend.clear_session()` and `gc.collect()` will only clear memory on your host VM, not on the TPU server.
- PS: You can also use the `steps_per_execution` flag to further improve the performance. Please see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tpu#train_the_model_using_keras_high-level_apis) for more info. Basically this prevents execution from continuously switching from CPU to TPU every step. If you set this to equal the number of training steps in an epoch, this will give you the best throughput.